# How do I use FFImageLoading's ".Preload()" in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, svg, preload, ffimageloading

In my current Xamarin.Forms project I use FFImageLoader to render my SVGs.
The Problem is that I would like to preload my images to avoid ugly "page building issues", but I don't understand how to realize it.

Current usage:

```
new SvgCachedImage {
    WidthRequest = 200,
    HeightRequest = 200,
    Source = new SvgImageSource(ImageSource.FromResource("Path.to.image.in.project.svg", 200, 200, true)
}
```

So what I want to do is loading the SvgImageSource into Cache and then "take" it from there, when needed.
Maybe I'm just to blind to find the solution in the documentation...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I am not sure about svg files but for pngs i use this ImageService.Instance.LoadCompiledResource("myimage.png").Preload();

Comment: For embeded resource you should use LoadEmbeddedResource option but I havent tested if it works for svg files. let me know also if it works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    ImageService.Instance.LoadEmbeddedResource("Path.to.image.in.project.svg")
                .WithCustomDataResolver(new SvgDataResolver(200, 200, true))
                .Preload();
```

Comment: Thank you very much :) But how do I load them from there?

Comment: Just use the same code you have in your initial post, cache will be used automatically.

Comment: That's what I tried, but it doesn't seem to work...
So on the first page I call what you suggested, but when I switch to the page, where the code I posted is used, it still takes the same time for the images to load.

Comment: Please enable FFImageLoading verbose logging and see what the cache keys are (via custom config - it's on the wiki)

Comment: Ok, so I activated logging and the problem seems to be that the preloading doesn't work:

**"[0:] Generating/retrieving image: resource://Path.to.image.in.project.svg;(size=48x48,dip=True)

[0:] Image loading failed: resource://Path.to.image.in.project.svg;(size=48x48,dip=True)

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: resource://Path.to.image.in.project.svg"**

But the svg definitely is there and marked as "Embedded Resource"...

Comment: Your preload method is called from another assembly, you must provide it manually (LoadEmbeddedResource override). Library doesn't know which one you want to use so it uses a current one which is used first..

Comment: Ok, now I don't get the error anymore, but it still doesn't seem to work correctly: **[0:] Generating/retrieving image: resource://Path.to.image.in.project.svg?assembly=[Assembly],%20Version=1.0.0.0,%20Culture=neutral,%20PublicKeyToken=null;(size=213x213,dip=True)**. I think there should be a key instead? Like **[0:] Generating/retrieving image: 2280242F13A3BCBCCDF8F8324A384425;(size=213x213,dip=True)**